# On record edit "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it."

Tags: page-layout

I have a record page layout with nothing but standard details component.

When I try to edit, not even save it, just click edit on any of the fields it gives me this:
[image: "]

Interestingly it shows me this screen 3 times.

This is the error in the "tecnical stuff":

```
[The requested resource does not exist]
_handleComponentError()@https://mycompany--partial.lightning.force.com/components/records/recordLayout2.js:2:15576
dispatchErrorEventFromLDS()@https://mycompany--partial.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/lookupDesktop.js:2:12566
wiredRecordUi()@https://mycompany--partial.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/lookupDesktop.js:2:11393
gi()@https://mycompany--partial.lightning.force.com/components/force/lds.js:2:164128
mi/</n</<()@https://mycompany--partial.lightning.force.com/components/force/lds.js:2:164415
mi/</</<()@https://mycompany--partial.lightning.force.com/components/force/lds.js:2:164853
```